# Folder bookmark from second (windows) drive stops working after reboot in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10

I try to link a folder from windows (dual-boot) and after each reboot it disappears.

Comment: If the partition isn't set to be automounted then it won't be and the shortcut only works after clicking on the partition (and consequently mounting it) in the file manager.